# VSCode foreach loop - The value of the local variable ignored is not used

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am using a foreach loop because I need that amount to be added to a separate array and that is the neatest way to do it. But VSCode reports a minor error because the variable in the foreach loop is not used...even though I don't need to use it here.

```
for (String ignored : array)
    indexes.add(firstIndex++);
```

I opened the project in Intellij and it fixed the error by changing the variable name to `ignored` and thus the error went away. But in VSCode it's not ignored and I don't know how to make it ignore it?

I've already considered using a normal for loop instead or using Intellij instead and I don't want to use those. I like VSCode better and the foreach loop looks neater, the error message warning is the only issue.

Comment: Someone's voted to close this for more clarity without stating what is not clear? Then the only thing that is not clear is the close request..A comment stating the issue would be infinitely more useful than an anonymous close request.

Comment: Actually, it might not be the best way to write code like this. You are using a parameter which is never used, so it's reasonable to raise a warning. It is recommended that you can use `len` of the array in the for loop so you don't need an unused `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` before the method or the class to suppress this warning.

rename the variable to `ignored` to suppress this warning is a gentle solution in IntelliJ IDEA. I had submitted a similar [feature request](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2388) on GitHub.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks, it's really almost as good as using the rename to 'ignored' method in Intellij. Interesting you made that suggestion to them, we'll see what they think of it.